# Fit a semicircle in a distribution: MATLAB

Tags: math-software

I have a set of data points which distribute around a semicircle. How can I fit a semicircle on that distribution in MATLAB? The data has two columns (X Y) and a number of rows (varying for different experiments).

Comment: Is it a simple semicircle you expect to be center at an origin and aligned with the $x$ or $y$ axis, or is it with respect to an arbitrary coordinate system?

Comment: How do you plan to measure the fit, the error of approximation by a semi-circle?

Comment: @rlgordonma: It is a distribution of points (result from a simulation). The distribution is in the form of a semicircle as I expected. But, to proceed, I need to fit the data points with a semicircle. The data has two columns X and Y (position coordinates).

Comment: What I was asking was, is there a function form for the fit, i.e. $y(x) = y_c +  \sqrt{r^2-(x-x_c)^2}$, or will you need to introduce a coordinate rotation as an additional parameter?

Answer (score 3):

One simple way would be to use the function `fminunc` which does unconstrained minimization.

Let's say you have data $x_i$ and $y_i$. Your hypothesis is that the fit on a circle, that is,

$$x_i^2 + y_i^2 = r^2 + \epsilon_i$$

where $r$ is to be determined. You can fit the radius by minimizing the sum of squared errors

$$S(r) = \sum_{i} e_i^2 = \sum_i (x_i^2 + y_i^2 - r^2)^2$$

and the optimal $r$ is the one which minimized this:

$$r^* = {\rm argmin}_r S(r)$$

First let's generate some data on a semicircle:

```
theta = pi * rand(100,1);
x = cos(theta) + 0.1 * randn(100,1);
y = sin(theta) + 0.1 * randn(100,1);
```

You can plot this and make sure it looks as you expect:

```
plot(x,y,'.'), grid on
```

[image]

Now you can find the radius that minimizes the error using `fminunc`. We expect the answer to be about 1, but we'll put 2 as our initial guess, so that the minimizer has to do some work:

```
r_opt = fminunc(@(r)sum((x.^2 + y.^2 - r^2).^2), 2);
```

And now you can plot this on top of your previous plot, to make sure it looks sensible:

```
hold on
xvals = linspace(-1,1,100);
plot(xvals, sqrt(r_opt^2-xvals.^2), 'r')
```

[image]

Comment: what if the data are not centered at the origin, or even parallel to an axis?

Comment: Then you need to modify the code appropriately!

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward method to fit a circle to a data set and obtain the value of radius and the coordinates of the center is given pages 12-13 in the paper "Régressions coniqiues, quadriques,..." published on Scribd :

http://www.scribd.com/JJacquelin/documents